# HTML Special Characters for fraction with equal Numerator and Denominator

Tags: html, special-characters

In my html page I have displayed fractions using html special character. My idea is to display 1/2, 2/2 and 3/3.

I have used `&frac13; for 1/3` and `&frac23; for 2/3` and the special charactera are displayed correctly. I took reference from this link [HTML Special Characters](http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html#fractions)

But when I tried using `&frac33; for 3/3` it is not working. It is just displaying as it is, not converting to special character.

Could you someone please tell me what is the html special character for 3/3.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>3</sub>
```

Result: <sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>

Comment: But the problem with using code is, the font size of 3/3 is little bigger compared to using &frac13;

Comment: Just convert everything to the code above then and don't use &frac13 if they don't match in sizing

Answer (score 2):

Not all fractions have their own special character. For those fractions (like 3/3) which don't have slanted fraction characters, use the HTML entity `&frasl;`:

`<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>3</sub>` = <sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There is no named (or numeric) character reference for a character representing 3/3, since there simply is no such character.

In theory, the FRACTION SLASH U+2044 “⁄” character (representable as `&frasl;` in HTML, among other thing) can be used between digits to suggest that rendering routines present the combination as a typographic fraction. In practice, only some typesetting programs can do this, and web browsers come nowhere near.

Trying to play with HTML markup and/or CSS to construct something that looks like a typographic fraction (comparable to ½ in appearance) tend to produce messy results, including uneven line spacing.

The practical option is to use just common notations like 2/2. But if you want something like a typographic fraction, you could use MathML with [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). More exactly, you would use the [`mfrac`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/mfrac) element in MathML with the attribute `bevelled="true"`. Sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Fractions with MathJax and MathML</title>
<script src=
"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
Here we have the common fraction ½, then
a simulation with HTML and CSS:
<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>.
Note that this tends to create uneven line spacing.
There are some cures to that, but let us see how MathML works:
<math>
<mfrac bevelled="true">
    <mn>1</mn>
    <mn>2</mn>
</mfrac>
</math>.
Some text here to demonstrate that line spacing has not
been disturbed here.
```

Sample rendering:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know some new code which I didn't seen before.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).